# If I connect my USB printer to my Raspberry Pi and share it with Samba do I still need a driver for the Pi?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, printing

I do not have the right drivers for my Raspberry Pi. That said, if i connect my Pi to my printer and share it with Samba, will I still need a driver to print via the wireless network? As per this guide - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-wireless-printer-raspberry-pi/

I would assume that my pi doesn't need drivers. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need drivers somewhere, but you may be in luck if the drivers are available for the OS on the computer you're printing from. Look under the *Adding Your Printer* section of the article you linked to. It mentions:

> Alternatively, click Select Another Make/Manufacturer and select Raw. You can let Windows handle the driver!"

Try installing the drivers on your computer, then set it up to print to the CUPS printer.

Comment: My MAC can't seem to be able to print on the printer - keeps saying looking for printer. Trying another method.